# How do I find the current Mission Control space number from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, spaces, mission-control, desktop

Is there any way to determine the number of the currently active Mission Control space/desktop in Mac OS X Lion from the command line?

Comment: Just curious. Why do you need to know the number of the current Mission Control desktop?

Comment: I have a load of desktop wallpapers, some good, some bad. With the old Spaces I had an automator workflow tied to a button that would find the name of the current wallpaper and trash the file if I pressed the button. That way I could delete pictures I no longer liked. With Mission Control, the only way I can see of doing this is by first knowing the number of the space I am viewing. If you can come up with an alternative method of finding and trashing the picture currently being viewed, then I am all ears.

Comment: I will have to think about it. That's pretty complicated, and pretty cool too!

Comment: The names of the spaces wallpapers are in com.apple.desktop, but I have no idea how to work out which one is for which space other than grepping for the names in this file and looking at the images. As I run 6 spaces and have thousands of images, it would be nice to be able to trash one I don't like if it pops up on the current space I am using.

Comment: I guess I will have to get my workflow to ask me which space I am in. That's probably the easiest solution in the absence of a key-value property that is easy to interrogate.

Answer (score 3):

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768684/osx-lion-applescript-how-to-get-current-space-from-mission-control) on the main SO site.. Seems simple enough (er not really)..

Hope this helps.